# Python local variable to global variable

Tags: python, function, variables, global, local

I'm trying to write a modular script, with functions

-Function 1
age = input("tell me your age : ")

-Function 2
weight = input("tell me your weight : ")

-Function 3
birthday = input("tell me your birthday : ")

**at the end, i want to send a mail outside functions like :**

mail_body = age + weight + birthday

Thanks you for your time !

Comment: Stack overflow is not a place to ask your homework !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Your functions should return values, not assign global variables.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could either use the return command at the end of function to deliver the information to where it is called

```
mail_body = age + weight + birthday
return mail_body
```

for example if your function is **mailinfo()** then you can process the info like

```
mail_body = mailinfo() #after using return command in function
```

---

Or you can declare **mail_body** as a global function at the start of program

```
mail_body = "placeholder"
global mail_body
```